# rST rendering problem: text is not flowing around sidebar

Tags: html, css, restructuredtext

I am trying to render a ReStructuredText file using `rst2html5` command of `docutils` package. The content of my rST file is as follows:

```
heading
=======

This is a line,

This is a line, too.


.. sidebar:: bar1

    item 1

    item 2



.. sidebar:: bar2

    - item 1

    - item 2


heading 1
---------

sub-heading 1
.............

sub-heading 2
.............
```

It has a section followed by two line to text, then two `sidebar` and finally a sub section followed by two sub-sub section. In the [description](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/0.4/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#sidebar) of the `sidebar` directive, it says that:

> A sidebar is typically offset by a border and "floats" to the side of the page; the document's main text may flow around it.

Unfortunately, if I render it with the `rst2html5` command it keeps an empty space in between the 2 line and the sub section instead of the sub section flowing around. If I render it with the `rst2html` command, the sub section flows around the sidebar and leaves no empty space.

This is the screenshot that rendered the rST file using `rst2html` command.
[image: Rendered using <code>rst2html</code> command]

This is the screenshot that rendered the rST file using `rst2html5` command.
[image: Rendered using <code>rst2html5</code> command]

What can I do to render the file to follow the text with `rst2html5` command?

Comment: Compare the style sheets between the two outputs, and modify the latter with styles for the sidebar from the former.

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks! I actually solved it by doing exactly that. I was just looking for a better solution as I am just a beginner in rST and possibly missed something.